# set display none to every tag with some class

Tags: css, display

I have a construct of html like this:

```
<article>
  <div class="no-feature-image">
   <another divs>...
  </div>
</article>
```

And now I want to add display:none to whole tag  witch has div with "no-feature-image". I tryed to do like this but it doesn't work:

```
article[no-feature-image] {
display:none
}
```

Ho can I make to not display every  with some specific class? Here I want to remove all articles without images :(

Comment: add to this article.no-feature-image {
display:none
}

Comment: No no this is adding me display:none to div with class .no-feature-image. I want to add display:none to whole tag <article>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
article:has(> .no-feature-image) {
  display:none
}
```

Comment: is it working on your side?

Comment: Yes this is the best solution thank U

Comment: @wenus it's not supported https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has ... only works on Safari so you cannot rely on it

Comment: @TemaniAfif - It works on Safari? It shouldn't do. `:has()` is only for the Snapshot profile - essentially querySelector() and querySelectorAll()

Comment: @Alohci yes you are right, I was thinking about the `:not()` selector that works only on Safari when we use a complex selector inside it. [like the one of this answer]